# emacs scala mode, cannot make it activate automatically

Tags: scala, emacs

I add the following to my ~/emacs file

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

Installed scala-mode2 via the emacs package manager

Add the following to my ~/.emacs file

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
     '("\\.scala" . scala-mode2)
     '("\\.sbt\\'" . scala-mode2)
     )
```

I then load any scala file. The scala-mode has not been activated, there is no highlighting.

I see the following in the 'messages' buffer:

*File mode specification error: (void-function scala-mode2)*

However if I enter `m-x scala-mode`, scala mode is activated and works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not very good.

I got it working by downloading the raw el files into .emacs.d/lisp/ as follows:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-fontlock.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-imenu.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-indent.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-lib.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-map.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-paragraph.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-prettify-symbols.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-prettify-syntax.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode-syntax.el
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode/master/scala-mode.el
```

Then just enable the mode by adding the following in .emacs:

```
(require 'scala-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.scala$" . scala-mode))
```

Comment: I wanted to edit, but there seems to be a permanent "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.". I wanted to add this: «and if using metals, or similar, add (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sc\\'" . scala-mode)) — for worksheets),  and (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sbt\\'" . scala-mode)) — for firing up lsp-metals (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Bad doc on github, should have been:

Add the following to my ~/.emacs file

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.scala" . scala-mode) '("\.sbt\'" . scala-mode) )
```

Comment: The code / syntax is wrong. Going to edit the other, right, answer of vpathak.